# Rails form checkbox helper with argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, form-helpers

I have a Rails form with a few checkboxes.  Here's the relevant part:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :roles %>
    <table>
      <tr><td>Admin</td><td>Sales</td><td>Moderator</td></tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%= f.check_box :is_admin? %></td>
        <td><%= f.check_box :is_sales? %></td>
        <td><%= f.check_box :is_moderator? %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This works, but ideally, instead of using `is_admin?` *etc.* I would like to use another method I wrote, `check_role`, which takes a string role name (*e.g.* 'admin').

```
def is_admin?
    self.check_role('admin')
end

# I'd like to use this method instead
def check_role(role_name)
    # checks the role name and returns true or false
end
```

I'm not sure how to do that because the `check_role` method takes 1 argument, but the documentation and all the examples I've viewed for the form helper `check_box` always use a method that takes zero arguments.

Is this possible using Rails form helpers, or am I stuck with using only zero argument methods?

Answer (score 0):

the doc says:

```
It’s intended that method returns an integer and if that integer is above zero...
```

try make you method return integer